# ¿Cómo guardar datos en un array empezando en el último indice utilizado en la iteracion previa de un for?

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, bucles

Quiero guardar los datos de arrayNumeros en pedazoArrayNumeros, pero a cachos, es decir, que en la primera iteracion del while, me guarde los 1ºs cuatro elementos, en la segunda los siguientes 4,etc.
y la cuestion es que por mas que intento, o me dan excepciones o me guarda en todas las iteraciones los primeros 4 elementos.
¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema para recorrer todo el array e ir guardando pedazos en cada iteracion?

```
    int[] arrayNumeros = {1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3, 6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4,};
    Arrays.sort(arrayNumeros);
    int[] pedazoArrayNumeros = new int[4];
    int casos = 3;

    while (casos > 0) {
        casos--;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumeros.length; i++) {
            int aux=0;
            for (int j = 0; j < pedazoArrayNumeros.length; j++) {
                pedazoArrayNumeros[aux] = arrayNumeros[j];
                ++aux;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pedazoArrayNumeros));
    }
```

Comment: No está claro (al menos para mi) lo que pretendes conseguir, la variable `pedazoArrayNumeros` almacena 4 números, es decir UNO de esos "cachos" que mencionas, pero no veo ninguna variable donde almacenenes TODOS los "cachos".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[] arrayNumeros = {1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3, 6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4,};
Arrays.sort(arrayNumeros);
int[] pedazoArrayNumeros = new int[4];
int aux=0;
while(aux<arrayNumeros.length){
        for(int i=0;i<pedazoArrayNumeros.length;i++){
            if(aux==arrayNumeros.length)
                //Si se llega al final de array se sale y conserva el valor anterior (En este caso por eso hay dos veces 5)
                break;
            else
                pedazoArrayNumeros[i]=arrayNumeros[aux];
            aux++;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pedazoArrayNumeros));
    }
```

La excepción te salta por que el tamaño de tu array no es multiplo del tamaño del pedazo ArrayNumeros, para eso es el if y los ultimos campos del array son los mismos que los anteriores. Ya que es un array de una dimension no en cada vuelta del bucle estas sobrescribiendo el anterior y no se guarda el valor. Para guardarlo usa un array de 2 dimensiones.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de haberte entendido, pero yo lo haría de la siguiente manera, utilizaría `List` en lugar de arrays Java, sería algo como:

```
int[] arrayNumeros = {1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3, 6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4,};
Arrays.sort(arrayNumeros);

List<List<Integer>> cachos = new ArrayList<>();
int  LIMITE_CACHOS = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumeros.length && cachos.size() < LIMITE_CACHOS;) {

    List<Integer> pedazo = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 4 && i < arrayNumeros.length; j++) {
        pedazo.add(arrayNumeros[i++]);                
    }
    cachos.add(pedazo);

}
System.out.println(cachos);
```

Con este código si pones un limite de cachos mayor del número existente, te genera una lista igual con todos los elementos y el último cacho con el número de elementos restante, el cual puede ser menor de 4.